# the problem with ajax i don't get the content

Tags: ajax, oop, post

On submit the `.saveInsurance` I get a 204 no content answer instead of getting the content of the page can anybody help me sometime I get a error in data
the error is

> examples.js:70 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...)[0].data is not
>   a function

the actual result is to get a 200 status code and get the content

```
var targetUrl = $(curInput).closest('.CustomeStepWizard').attr('data-url');
var dataSW = $(curInput).closest('.CustomeStepWizard')[0].data;
if (targetUrl)    
{
    bindObj ={  
        url: targetUrl, 
        data: dataSW 
    };

    $(curInput).closest('.CustomeStepWizard').find('.saveInsuranceBTN')
            .removeAttr('disabled').click(function () {
                createPostRequest(this.url, bindObj.data);
            }
            .bind(bindObj));
} 
else {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As your HTML file is not shown, I want to believe that you have some data attribute attached to the $(.CustomeStepWizard) object. However, this data could be retrieved by using

$(.CustomeStepWizard)[0].data(); /*returns all data. Mind the () after the data.*/
    $(.CustomeStepWizard)[0].data('foo');
    $(.CustomeStepWizard)[0].attr('data-foo');  /* retrieve a particular data. */